# A problem about irrational number

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I'm dealing with the following problem:

By using piegonhole principal, prove that for any positive irrational number $r$ and positive real numbers $x,y \in \left( {0,1} \right)$, $x < y$, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $x \le nr - \left[ {nr} \right] \le y$, where $\left[{nr}\right]$ is the integral part of $nr$.

Attempt: Clearly, $r,2r,3r, \ldots $ are all different and also the fractional parts of them are all different. Otherwise, $r$ would be rational. I think that if the fractional parts of $r,2r,3r, \ldots $ cover the interval $\left( {0,1} \right)$, proof is over. Here, piegons are  the fractional parts of $r,2r,3r, \ldots $ and holes are the real numbers in the interval $\left( {0,1} \right)$.

I don't know whether it is true or not.

Comment: The technical term for what you call "covers" is "dense in." The set of fractional parts of $r,2r,\dots$ is "dense in" $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Consider $0, \{r\}, \{2r\},\ldots, \{nr\}, 1$ and divide $(0, 1)$ in $n+1$ equal parts. By the pigeonhole principle, at least one part will contain two numbers, say $\{pr\}$ and $\{qr\}$; then $$\left|\{pr\}-\{qr\}\right|\lt \frac{1}{n+1}.$$ Remember $\{pr\}=pr- \left\lfloor pr\right\rfloor$. This is [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Dirichlet's theorem says that if $\alpha$ is irrational, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exist integers $p$ and $q$ such that $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $1 \le q \le n$ such that:
$$
\left\lvert \alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right\rvert < \frac{1}{(n + 1) q}
$$
This inequality is the same as $\lvert q \alpha - p \rvert < 1 / (n + 1)$. The $n + 2$ numbers $0$, $k \alpha - \lfloor k \alpha \rfloor$ for $1 \le k \le n$, $1$ are all different. By the pigeonhole principle, there are two that differ by less than $1/(n + 1)$. If they are $a \alpha$ and $b \alpha$, take $q = \lvert b - a \rvert$; if one is $0$ or $1$, take $q = \lvert a \rvert$.

What you want is almost the same.